# MsBuild ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment excludes all folders

Tags: c#, msbuild, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm having 2 folders in my project directory:

> .\Scripts

and

> .\bin\Scripts

I'd like to exclude the "**bin\Scripts**" directory from publishing. This is what I tried to do in a wpp.targets file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include=".\bin\Scripts"></ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
</ItemGroup>
```

This does not exclude the folder but when i just add "**Scripts**" to the include property, both folders will be excluded.

How do I exclude just "**bin\Scripts**"?

Ok, so the main problem is, that the asset files are being copied to the output directory. I can not change the project settings. Is there a way to prevent the content files from being copied to the output directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the.\ and if that doesn't work replace it with $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work :(.

Comment: You should not have a bin\Scripts directory. Ensure all your content files have the property `Copy in the output directory` to `do not copy`